# Implementing JavaScript-like Closure in Ruby

Tags: javascript, ruby

I find it difficult to program without using closures in the following pattern:

```
function outerFunction(input) {
  var closureVar = "I'm here with ";

  function innerFunction() {
    return closureVar + input;
  }

  return innerFunction();
}

outerFunction('outer input'); // I'm here with outer input
```

This makes sense to me.  The outerFunction defines an environment that innerFunction has reference to upon invocation.

I would like to see how Ruby accomplishes the same thing.  I understand Ruby uses blocks, procs and lambas, but I cannot seem to achieve the same lexical scoping as I can with JavaScript.

Ruby naive attempt:

```
def outer_function
  list = [ 1, 2, 3 ]

  list.each { |item| print item }
end

# Fails because list has an undefined method on the second iteration of the loop
```

another attempt

```
def outer_function
  list = Proc.new { return [ 1, 2, 3 ] }

  list.call.each { |item| another_function item }
end

def another_function item
  puts item
end

# Same problem
```

So, how can I achieve this pattern in Ruby?

Comment: What do you mean by *# Fails because list has an undefined method on the second iteration of the loop*?

Comment: Sorry, I had left my code incomplete.  I am in fact calling another function within the loop. So I believe once it calls that function it resets list to nil.  I used a begin and rescue block and that is to me what appears to be happening.

Comment: Show the actual code then.

Comment: I don't see any issue with the code `list = [ 1, 2, 3 ];  list.each { |item| print item }`

Comment: Weird.  Totally lost on this one

Comment: The two halves of your question are completely unrelated to each other. There are no closures and no lexical scoping in your second half. The Ruby code you posted is also in no way related to the ECMAScript you posted. And lastly, the first snippet of Ruby code you posted works as-is, the second just needs the `return` keyword either replaced with `next` or just removed entirely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While Javascript has one type of lambda construct (an anonymous function), Ruby has several. The most common are blocks (passed to methods as in `each` in your example), Procs (which are like blocks that are bound to a execution context which they retain even when passed around), and Lambdas which are probably closest to anonymous functions. I won't go into the details of Procs vs Lambdas here.

Here are examples of these constructs in Ruby:

```
# Using a block + yield
def my_method(arg)
  puts arg + yield(3)
end

my_method(5) { |arg| arg * 2 }
# => 11

# Binding the block to a Proc then using #call
def print(&block)
  puts block.call
end

# Creating a Proc that can be passed around and then #called
def other_method(arg, other_args*)
  arg.call(other_args*)
end

var = 3
prc = Proc.new { puts var }
other_method(prc)

# Creating a Lambda using stabby syntax
num = 3
l = -> (arg) { arg + 2 + num }
other_method(l, 1)
```

In Ruby you could write your JS example as:

```
def outer(input)
  closure_var = "I'm here with "

  inner = -> { closure_var + input }

  inner.call
end

outer('outer input')
```

In IRB:

```
jbodah@Joshs-MacBook-Pro-2 2.1.3p242 ~ (none) $ irb
irb(main):001:0>     def outer(input)
irb(main):002:1>       closure_var = "I'm here with "
irb(main):003:1>
irb(main):004:1*       inner = -> { closure_var + input }
irb(main):005:1>
irb(main):006:1*       inner.call
irb(main):007:1>     end
=> :outer
irb(main):008:0>
irb(main):009:0*     outer('outer input')
=> "I'm here with outer input"
```

Answer (score 3):

```js
function outerFunction(input) {
  var closureVar = "I'm here with ";

  function innerFunction() {
    return closureVar + input;
  }

  return innerFunction();
}

console.log(outerFunction('outer input')); // I'm here with outer input
```

Let's first re-write your ECMAScript to use function expressions:

```js
const outerFunction = function (input) {
  const closureVar = "I'm here with ";

  const innerFunction = function () {
    return closureVar + input;
  }

  return innerFunction();
}

console.log(outerFunction('outer input')); // I'm here with outer input
```

Now let's re-write that into more modern style:

```js
const outerFunction = input => {
  const closureVar = "I'm here with ";

  const innerFunction = () => closureVar + input;

  return innerFunction();
};

console.log(outerFunction('outer input')); // I'm here with outer input
```

Now, it's actually fairly simple to translate this to Ruby:

```ruby
outer_function = -> input {
  closure_var = "I'm here with "

  inner_function = -> { closure_var + input }

  inner_function.()
}

puts outer_function.('outer input') # I'm here with outer input
```

As you can see, the translation is actually pretty straightforward and the semantics are similar. It is, however, not very idiomatic Ruby. In general, objects and methods are preferred over closures for encapsulating state, but sometimes, closures are useful and used.

A more idiomatic style might be something like this:

```ruby
def outer_method(input)
  closure_var = "I'm here with "

  inner_function = -> { closure_var + input }

  inner_function.()
end

puts outer_method('outer input') # I'm here with outer input
```

But for such a small toy example it's hard to say and hard to demonstrate what idiomatic Ruby would look like.

If you are interested in stuff like this, you might want to look through a [toy project of mine](http://joergwmittag.github.io/lambdaconscarcdr/), where I show how to implement linked lists using nothing but closures in a variety of languages including Clojure and various other Lisps, Smalltalk and some of its descendants, ECMAScript and CoffeeScript, Ruby, Python, PHP, Perl, etc. Note that the code looks very similar in most languages, but note also that the code is very un-idiomatic in almost all of the languages, except Scheme and maybe Clojure. It isn't even idiomatic CommonLisp as far as I can tell.

---

The Ruby code you posted in the second half of your question is completely unrelated to either the code or the concepts in the first half of your question: there are no closures, no issues of lexical scoping, and there is no need to use them.

In fact, the first snippet you posted just works as-is:

```ruby
def outer_function
  list = [ 1, 2, 3 ]

  list.each { |item| print item }
end

outer_function
# 123
```

The second just has a tiny problem:

```ruby
def outer_function
  list = Proc.new { return [ 1, 2, 3 ] }

  # The call to `each` is dead code since the call to `list.call` will already return
  list.call.each { |item| another_function item }
end

# This method never gets called
def another_function item
  puts item
end

outer_function
# => [1, 2, 3]
```

`return` is used to return a value from a *method*. So, what method does the `return` return from? Well, it returns from `outer_function`, since that's the only method there! `list` is a `Proc`, not a method. To return from a `Proc`, you use the `next` keyword instead:

```ruby
def outer_function
  list = Proc.new { next [ 1, 2, 3 ] }

  list.call.each { |item| another_function item }
end

def another_function item
  puts item
end

outer_function
# 1
# 2
# 3
```

Alternatively, you could leave out the `next` altogether, since the last expression evaluated inside a compound expression (a block, a method, a class, whatever) is its return value anyway:

```ruby
def outer_function
  list = Proc.new { [ 1, 2, 3 ] }

  list.call.each { |item| another_function item }
end

def another_function item
  puts item
end

outer_function
# 1
# 2
# 3
```

Or, you could replace the `Proc` with a lambda (which is actually also a `Proc` but with slightly different semantics):

```ruby
def outer_function
  list = -> { return [ 1, 2, 3 ] }

  list.call.each { |item| another_function item }
end

def another_function item
  puts item
end

outer_function
# 1
# 2
# 3
```

There are two semantic differences between `Proc`s (created by `Proc.new` or `Kernel#proc`) and lambdas (created by `Kernel#lambda` or the stabby lambda literal `-> (params) { code }`): `return` in a `Proc` returns from the lexically enclosing method (just like in a block) whereas `return` in a lambda returns from the lambda itself (just like in a method), and the argument binding semantics of `Proc`s are the same as those of blocks, whereas the argument binding semantics of lambdas are the same as those of methods.

To recap: there are two differences, `return` and argument binding. And in both cases, `Proc` behaves like a block and lambda behaves like a method. Mnemonic: `Proc` rhymes with "block", and "lambda" and "method" are both Greek.

Answer (score 0):

The below will do it for you , just be mindful inner_function is not really a method.Hence it is a lambda which behaves like a method. read more here [LINK](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Proc.html) .

```
def outer_function(item)
    outer_variable = "input"
    inner_function = lambda { puts item   puts outer_variable }
    inner_function[]
end

outer_function "I'm here with " # prints "I'm here with input"
```